# How do you pass overload operator members of classes as function pointers?

Tags: c++, types, parameters, overloading, function-pointers

For example, if I wanted to pass

```
ostream& std::ostream::operator << (int i);
```

into a function such as

```
void func(ostream& (*out)(int), ...);
```

then how would I go about doing that?

Doing

```
func(std::ostream::operator << (int))
```

surely does not work and

```
typedef ostream& (*out)(int);
out o = std::ostream::operator << (int);
func(o);
```

throws a compile-time error when trying to assign o. So how does one point to overloaded operators? (casting to type out does not work in this situation either)

---

After playing around with the code, my question is now this: why is it that non-member, overloaded operators i.e

```
ostream& operator << (ostream&, classX)
```

return a void* and not a pointer to a function?

If I do

```
typedef ostream& (*out)(ostream&,classX);
```

I can only make it

```
void* v = ostream& operator << (ostream&,classX);
```

and not

```
out o = ostream& operator << (ostream&,classX);
```

which prints the error messsage

```
190: error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&, classX)'
```

Comment: Isn't the problem here that you're trying to assign a non-static member function to a function pointer?

Comment: Yes. But why does that prevent a non-static member function from being pointed to? Is it because all non-static members are instantiation dependent?

Comment: Could you provide the compiler-error message, please?

Answer (score 3):

Depend on how you have overloaded the operator.

The signature (The type of the pointer that points to) of a function is:

- `RETURN_TYPE(*)(PARAMETERS_TYPES)` if its a global function.
- `RETURN_TYPE (CLASS_NAME::*)(PARAMETERS_TYPES)` if its a member function.

If you have a function called `f` and a function that gets a pointer to a function as parameter, f is passed as follows:

- `g(f)` if f is a global function.
- `g(&CLASS_NAME::f)` if f is a member function of CLASS_NAME class.

Note that function pointers and member function pointers are not compatible.

So if your operator is overloaded as a member function, like `operator+=` you should use the second version. If not, you should use the first.

Comment: But if you defined rtype operator += (type1,type2) it would not be a member function and therefore compatible with the first sig, right?

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify the assignment here. There is no need to specify the whole signature, since the correct overload can be inferred from the type on the left hand side.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Foo
{
    int x;
};

ostream& operator<< (ostream &a, const Foo& b)
{
    return a << b.x;
}

typedef ostream& (*Func) (ostream &, const Foo&);

int main() {
    Func func = &operator<<;
    (*func)(cout, Foo{42});
}
```